# How to make URL for independent Host

Tags: ajax, spring, http, url

I written a controller that's returning *Json* format data ,this is from the 
  `url: localhost:8080/collection-ui/api/permissions/findall"`,and used it in my page for dynatree view structure. my code is,

```
$.ajax({
       url: localhost:8080/collection-ui/api/permissions/findall",
       success: function( treeData ) {
           var tree = $("#tree2").dynatree("getTree");
           var rootNode = $("#tree2").dynatree("getRoot");             
           var TopRoot = rootNode.addChild({
                title: 'Select All',
                tooltip:'Select All'
            });
```

Here my problem is..I called the *URL using localhost* right,so this is working only in my system.I want to call for all host(dynamic),
How can i cal this url without using Localhost? plz anybody help...

Main thing is that i gave like this `url:/collection-ui/api/permissions/findall....`its working but while updating using `url:/collection-ui/api/rolepermissions/update....`it does't work i mean can't insert into DB Table...So anybody help  please

Comment: Just leaving out the host is OK. Your updating call must have other issues.

Comment: No its not working....while insert it shows error like "error[object:Object]".....I tried url:/collection-ui/api/rolepermissions/update and also tried with url:collection-ui/api....but does't work. So plz help me

Comment: for url "/collection-ui/api/rolepermissions/update", the http method must be put, are you using put in your ajax request ? Also was the update function working when you used localhost ?

Comment: yes.Update function is working when use the localhost.And POST method is not working so i want to fix it then only i can go for PUT, i mean Update function.plz help me for post